# How do I fix "No Internet Access" message in Network And Sharing Center on Windows 7 when connected through corporate proxy?

Tags: networking, windows-7, proxy

The question pretty much says it all. I see all of our Windows 7 machines have a little exclamation point saying "No Internet Access", when they do indeed have access.

Our proxy is Bluecoat if that helps. I'm not the network admin, but I will try and provide any other requested info. Thanks!

Comment: Talk to you network admin or helpdesk?

Comment: Yeah, they don't know either. I'm a developer, and I'm currently setting up an image for new PCs, and I would like that gone. I'd rather hear if anyone has the actual solution for it.

Comment: Your network administrators don't know how to connect your PC to your network?

Comment: No, it is connected, and has internet access, but the icon just says "No Internet Access". I'm guessing it has to do with our proxy, and I'm looking for a way to make windows be aware  that it is, in fact, connected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows determines if the machines have Internet access by attempting to download a small text file. It can tell if you have connectivity when it's able to download, and if the result doesn't match what's expected it then knows you're behind some sort of web login-required gateway.

The whole thing's laid out [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee126135(WS.10).aspx).

Seems there's been a full exposé on the topic over at [SuperUser](http://blog.superuser.com/2011/05/16/windows-7-network-awareness/).

So my guess is that you're getting this URL (http://www.msftncsi.com/ncsi.txt) blocked. Your options are:

1. Disable NCSI
2. Run your own NCSI web server and modify the registry to point there
3. Unblock the Microsoft NCSI server.

Comment: It works (setting the registry to disable it), but only after the PC has been on for a while.  Good enough for me at this point. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Verification URLs change on Windows 10 and Windows Server 2016:

Before: `www.msftncsi.com/ncsi.txt`

On Windows 10 or 2016: `www.msftconnecttest.com/connecttest.txt`

It is important to verify the branch of the Windows registry, here you can see the URLs:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\NlaSvc\Parameters\Internet
```

Extracted from: http://www.sysadmit.com/2017/07/windows-signo-de-admiracion-en-conexion.html